# Load json response data to the grid

Tags: android, json, gridview, jsonresponse

I have a dynamic grid which can hold image and its description. Those details are inside the responseJson. I want to fill the grid using those details inside responseJson. How can I pass Description, ImageURL to the grid? any help will be appreciated.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);

        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        mQuickReturnView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer);
        mQuickReturnView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer1);
        mQuickReturnView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer2);

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try
        {
            String[] Description = new String[responseJson.length()];
            String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1"))
                {
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    ImageURL[i] = object.getString("ImageURL");
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("Description"));
                    Description[i] = object.getString("Description");

                    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description, ImageURL);
                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
        }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is my customgrid adopter

```
    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] Description,String[] ImageURL ) {
            mContext = c;
            this.ImageURL = ImageURL;
            this.Description = Description;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Description.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View grid;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {  

                grid = new View(mContext);
                grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                textView.setText(Description[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(ImageURL[position]); //error - The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)

            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }

            return grid;
        }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? Does your code work?

Comment: Code works and log.i in onTaskCompleted method shows the values for both the attributes as well. I want to pass Description and ImageURL to the grid?

Comment: I want to know how to send data to CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description, ImageURL); from responseJson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

    try
    {
        description = new String[responseJson.length()];
        imageUrl = new String[responseJson.length()];
        for (int n = 0; n < responseJson.length(); n++)
        {
            JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(n);
            if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1"))
            {
                Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                imageUrl[i] = object.getString("ImageURL");
                Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("Description"));
                description[i] = object.getString("Description");
            }
        }
        adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), description, imageURL);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
        catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my above code, I got the idea from your answer and changed the code as shown in my edited question. In my customgrid adopter class it gives error for image because I have set it as string, I want to fix that error

Comment: You need to load image from server. Try Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso. Instead of `imageView.setImageResource(ImageURL[position]);` type `Picasso.with(context).load(ImageURL[position]).into(imageView);` and don't forget about `INTERNET` permission!